# Shutting down and restarting app in test activities within a Test suite

Tags: android, junit, robotium, test-suite

I'm using Robotium to write test case to an Android app. I have two testing activities. In the first test activity checking log in procedure in the app and then terminate the app.

```
public static Test suite() {
               TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(AllTests.class.getName());
               //$JUnit-BEGIN$

               suite.addTestSuite(LoginActivityTest.class);

               suite.addTestSuite(MainScreenActivityTest.class);
               //$JUnit-END$
               return suite;
}
```

But due to the termination in the first test the second test will fail.
What can i do in order to restart the app, in the test suite?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "terminate the app"? Do you mean you stop the current activity?

Answer (score 0):

Each test case must be indepently executed. They may not rely on previous success or error. This is a general hint for all unit tests.

You can use `setup()` and `tearDown()` with robotium (at least from version 3.0 on) to execute code before and after each test case, no matter if the test case failed.

`setup()` and `tearDown()` will be called before each test case, so that you are not coupling the test cases with each other.
An example is shown in the ["Get started" Tutorial (pdf)](http://robotium.googlecode.com/files/Test%20Android%20Sample%20App-3_0.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @furtwart. I'm not sure you fully undersand my question. Every test activity has its own setup and teardown, but, when LoginActivityTes is finished, the app closed totally and MainScreenActivityTest won't run at all. How do I make it to start the app again?

Comment: Ok, I missed that part, thanks for the addition. But nonetheless, you have coupled your test cases too tightly. They may not depend on each other. How to restart the app is beyond my knowledge.